# How to create HTML report showing only log messages and no stdout call (print statements of the code)

Tags: python, error-logging, python-logging, pytest-html-reporter

I am learning pytest and logging using pycharm and python 3.9.6. I wanted to log the desired messages in the HTL report. I am using `logging.getLogger(__name__)` class for creating a logger object. **all i wanted is to display only the log messages** and **no print statements from my code (showing as stdout call in my HTML report)** in my HTML report.

I tried using `--show-capture=log` but i think it is only valid for failed tests. but in my case there is no failed tests. I am using `--html=report.html` cli command to generate report.

How can i generate a HTML report containg only log messages and no "Captured stdout call" as currently showing in my report? I want only the "Captured log call" in my report means only the logs that i am trying to print.

[image: HTML Report image]